# how to access array list and validate the value with AND conditions

Tags: java, groovy

I got the response as follow:

```
{
    "cartId": "default",
    "cartLines": [
        {
            "testid": "123",
            "isDeleted": false,
            "name": "peter",
        },
        {
            "testid": "123",
            "isDeleted": true,
            "name": "mary",
        }
    ],
    "type": "test"
}
```

I would like to make sure the value of  `"name": "peter"`
when query condition is `"testid": "123"` **AND** `"isDeleted": false`

what class can i use? Either java or groovy scripting language is good.

this is the usual way i did assertion, straightforward. the println(test_info) returned response i gave at above.

now i wanted to use for more conditions.

```
//SQL statement
String dbQuery2 = /SELECT * FROM public.tests where test_id = 'default'/


//Connect to PostgresSQL, global variable is stored at profile
List results = CustomKeywords.'test.database.getPostgresSQLResults'(GlobalVariable.dbConnString2 , GlobalVariable.dbUsername2 , GlobalVariable.dbPassword2 ,GlobalVariable.dbDriver2 ,dbQuery2 )
println(results)


//print the "test_info" column
String test_info = results.get(0).get('test_info')
println(test_info)

//convert to json format and verify result
def test_infojson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(new String(test_info))
println('Database test_info response text: \n' + JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(test_infojson)))

assert test_info.contains("peter")
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below solution is in java:

You need have a class to represent your JSON structure.

```
class Response {
  String cardId;
  String type;
  List<Cartline> cartlines;

  //Constructor

  //Getters and Setters

}

class Cartline {
  String name;
  String testid;
  boolean isDeleted;

  //Constructor

  //Getters and Setters
}
```

Then in your main code, you can do as shown below:

```
import org.json.*;

String jsonString = ... ; //assign your JSON String here
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);

JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("cartLines");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    String name = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
    String testId = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("testId"); 
    Boolean isDeleted = arr.getJSONObject(i).getBoolean("isDeleted");

 if (name.equals("peter") && testId. equals("123") && isDeleted == false) {
      // do your stuff
  }
}
```

You can access the jar file here : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

Comment: many thanks. i have learned new class and it works fine. import org.json.*